# Kubernetes deployment through azure devops pipeline unable to fetch image from artifactory

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, artifactory

Kubernetes deployment through azure devops pipeline unable to fetch image from artifactory

Deployment is getting failed and below error can be seen in the events

```
98m         Warning   Failed                  pod/filebrowser-deployment-69c89f574f-xwcs8    Failed to pull image "dscdr-ltd-discover-docker-dev-l.artifactory.utc.com/3rd-parties/filebrowser:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "dscdr-ltd-discover-docker-dev-l.artifactory.utc.com/3rd-parties/filebrowser:latest": failed to resolve reference "dscdr-ltd-discover-docker-dev-l.artifactory.utc.com/3rd-parties/filebrowser:latest": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 401
98m         Warning   Failed                  pod/filebrowser-deployment-69c89f574f-xwcs8    Error: ErrImagePull
98m         Normal    BackOff                 pod/filebrowser-deployment-69c89f574f-xwcs8    Back-off pulling image "dscdr-ltd-discover-docker-dev-l.artifactory.utc.com/3rd-parties/filebrowser:latest"
98m         Warning   Failed                  pod/filebrowser-deployment-69c89f574f-xwcs8    Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

configured secrets with the credential i am able to login but when it is getting deployed through artifactory, image pull is failing

Comment: You have to specify the secret to use either in the deployment spec or in the serviceaccount. Search for imagePullSecret in the doc

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a token that allows you to download from the Docker private repository.

After that you will need to define the "imagePullSecrets" parameter in your Deployment.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: i have configured imagepullsecret, i am able to pull image using docker pull but getting above error when executing through pipeline